# How to connect Powered Subwoofer to Mixer?

Tags: speakers, mixer, setup, stage, subwoofer

I have two [Alto TS210 Powered Active Speakers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018W4719I) connected to [Yamaha MG06 Mixer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I2J4WJG), which is then connected to my laptop via [Stereo Y-Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZKM3SHK). That setup is working fine, however, I would like to now add a sub-woofer.

Can I use the [Polk Audio PSW125 Sub-woofer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OY6CVI) in my setup? How do I go about doing that? This sub is powered and does not require an AMP, it also has built-in crossover.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

At first I was reluctant to answer this question, as I believe in order to do this properly, will cost more than the value of said sub-woofer.

However as nobody else has commented, I will give you an answer on how you can do this.

There are two problems we need to overcome:

1. The mixer has no further outputs to connect the subwoofer.
2. The subwoofer has unbalanced inputs, which seems to be at "Consumer Line-Level

So now we need to do the following:

- Take the mix-output from both Alto TS210's, to feed the subwoofer.
- "convert those from "balanced / professional line level" to "unbalanced / consumer line level"

As a picture is a thousands words, something like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have drawn two "box's" in the picture, which will have to do the conversion.

This can be done with some equipment, and here is an example:

[image]
[source:https://www.thomann.de/ie/sonifex_redbox_rbbl2.htm](https://www.thomann.de/ie/sonifex_redbox_rbbl2.htm)

Using this example you can use input-1 and output-1 to do exactly what you need.

However the cost of this type of equipment may be more expensive than actually buying a subwoofer with proffessional line level inputs/outputs, which actually does that without additional equipment.

There are plenty of examples of alternative subwoofers which will do this, let me provide one here:

https://www.thomann.de/ie/fun_generation_pl_15_sub_a.htm

You would use "input" on the subwoofer to feed from the outputs of the mixing desk, then use "high pass out" on the subwoofer to connect your Alto's.

[image]

(I have no affiliation with either website or products mentioned in this answer, they are given as samples only)

Comment: Edwin's answer is correct. But if you're in an environment with not too much RF noise, instead of the expensive converter, you can use an XLR to RCA cable from the MIX output on each speaker to the sub.

Comment: The MixOut of the TS are line level balanced output. Use a passive DI Box (which are bidirectional) like the Radial AV which has also RCA connectors. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5e3R.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5e3R.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but if you don't use the headphone output on the mixer, just run a stereo 1/4" to rca y-splitter cable to the rca inputs of the subwoofer. Otherwise, I'd have to agree that it would be more trouble/expensive than it is worth.

Comment: At your own risk (of damaging the preamp or amp circuitry in the sub woofer) Headphones out voltages are much higher than consumer-line-in voltages.

Comment: Good point; I didn't really think about that... Just don't turn the headphone volume up too high :) It's not really a satisfactory solution anyway you know? :)

Comment: And.... the headphones out, has a very low impedance. According to the data-sheet: 33 Ohm.

Answer (score 1):

PreSonus has come to the rescue! Check out:

PreSonus MicroStation BT

at your fav search engine. It allows you to connect your mixer to active speakers (studio or pa), as well as your hifi rca input active subwoofer for 2.1 outputs. It even throws bluetooth connection into the mix as well as an extra headphone connection and a volume control.

And no, I am not affiliated with PreSonus. Although they can feel free anytime to send me free stuff. Just saying...